The JavaScript `fetch' function works for me on Windows and Linux, but not on Android
My webpage uses JavaScript to call a PHP function using fetch(). The page and the called PHP page are both in the same domain. The page works fine on Windows and Linux, but fetch() fails on Android (it seems to do nothing). I don't know how to get to Developer Tools on Android or to view server errors, but there are no errors logged by my Linux Apache server when I run on Linux or by my Windows Apache server when I run on Windows. I've tried applying a variety of CORS headers with no luck, but this should not be a CORS issue.
I apologize if this issue is off-topic for this forum; perhaps someone could recommend a better forum?
